# Python scraping email protection address from href link

Tags: python, email, web-scraping, href, data-extraction

I want to get email adresses from :
[1]: https://thenationalweddingdirectory.com.au/suppliers/wedding-venues/queensland/the-dock-mooloolaba-events/

right now I have the code, but how can i scrap the email address from the clicked link?

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession    

url = 'https://thenationalweddingdirectory.com.au/explore/?category=wedding-venues&region=melbourne&sort=top-rated'

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=1)
products = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="finderListings"]/div[2]', first=True)

for item in products.absolute_links:
r = s.get(item)
print(r.html.find('li.lmb-calltoaction a', first=True))
```

Comment: Did you read the warning message you get?  They are using CloudFlare to protect their addresses SPECIFICALLY to block people like you.  You can't get the email addresses.  CloudFare is good at what they do.

Comment: Hi I got a result like this  <Element 'a' href='/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#660509081207051226090a0f0802071203070e091315034805090b480713' rel=('nofollow',)>

Comment: Right.  Did you try bringing up that URL in a browser?  That URL goes to a CloudFlare provider that knows how to use that hex string to send an email, but does not expose the address itself.

Comment: Also there are email-docede.min.js if you want to play with https://thenationalweddingdirectory.com.au/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Email**, telephone is on the page, there are one json with all info you need.
Also you have some "ajax" request to get all **URLs** to visit.

```py
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

params = {
    'mylisting-ajax': '1',
    'action': 'get_listings',
    'form_data[page]': '0',
    'form_data[preserve_page]': 'false',
    'form_data[category]': 'wedding-venues',
    'form_data[region]': 'melbourne',
    'form_data[sort]': 'top-rated',
    'listing_type': 'place',
}

response = requests.get('https://thenationalweddingdirectory.com.au/', params=params)
# get all urls
results = re.findall("https://thenationalweddingdirectory.com.au/suppliers/wedding-venues/melbourne/[a-zA-Z-]*/",
                     response.text.replace("\\", ""))
headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
for result in results:
    print("Navigate: " + result)
    response = requests.get(result, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    scripts = soup.find_all("script")
    for script in scripts:
        if "LocalBusiness" in script.text:
            data = json.loads(script.text)
            print("Name: " + data["name"])
            print("Telephone: " + data["telephone"])
            print("Email: " + data["email"])
            break
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Navigate: https://thenationalweddingdirectory.com.au/suppliers/wedding-venues/melbourne/metropolis-events/
Name: Metropolis Events
Telephone: 03 8537 7300
Email: info@metropolisevents.com.au
Navigate: https://thenationalweddingdirectory.com.au/suppliers/wedding-venues/melbourne/cotham-dining/
Name: Cotham Dining
Telephone: 0411 931 818
Email: hello@cothamdining.com.au
```

Comment: now I get the data
for your help
this will be very helpful
Thanks